# MYSQL INNER JOIN unexpected result

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having a problem on my MySQL Inner join. My `INNER JOIN` doesn't give me my desired result. I have **Table1** that contains the `TrackNo` only then **Table2** contains the details of **Table1** per `trackNo`.

**>> Table Structure:**

[image]

**>> SQL Code:**

```
SELECT tr.trackNo AS 'TrackNo',
       trD.Status,
       MAX(trD.DatePosted) AS `Date/Time`
FROM Tracking AS tr
INNER JOIN TrackingDetails AS trD
ON tr.trackNo = trD.trackNo
WHERE tr.ClientID='client01'
AND trD.trackNo IN ('xx000001','xx000002','xx000003')
AND trD.DatePosted IS NOT NULL 
AND trD.Status IN (
                'Received',
                'Logged',
                'Prepped',
                'Analyzed',
                'Reviewed',
                'Final Report',
                'Invoiced')
GROUP BY tr.trackNo
ORDER BY tr.trackNo ASC
```

Here's the result query above:

[image]

As you can see the query result image above is correct except for `Status` column.Where did I go wrong on my `SQL` Query? Did I miss something?

**>> Desired output:**

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+
|  TrackNo |  Status  |      Date/Time      |
+==========+==========+=====================+
| xx000001 | Logged   | 2015-03-09 17:53:14 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
| xx000002 | Prepped  | 2014-08-15 17:19:00 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
| xx000003 | Analyzed | 2014-10-10 11:12:00 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the code producing those results? You have `SELECT tr.trackNo AS 'TrackNo'` but that seems to be coming out as `trackingNo` and I don't see any `DatePosted` field in the `TrackingDetails` table which I'm assuming is TABLE2 above

Comment: @colmde: oopss. My bad. I modified the exact table. yes TABLE2 is TrackingDetails and `Date/Time` = `DatePosted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should gives you the correct result:

```
select * from TrackingDetails as a join (
    SELECT tr.trackNo AS 'TrackNo',
           MAX(trD.DatePosted) AS 'Date_Time'
    FROM Tracking AS tr
    INNER JOIN TrackingDetails AS trD
    ON tr.trackNo = trD.trackNo
    WHERE tr.ClientID='client01'
    AND trD.trackNo IN ('xx000001','xx000002','xx000003')
    AND trD.DatePosted IS NOT NULL 
    AND trD.Status IN (
                    'Received',
                    'Logged',
                    'Prepped',
                    'Analyzed',
                    'Reviewed',
                    'Final Report',
                    'Invoiced')
    GROUP BY tr.trackNo
    ORDER BY tr.trackNo ASC

) as x on x.TrackNo = a.trackNo and a.DatePosted = x.'Date_Time'
```

If you use group by in mysql it is not specified wich values you get from columns which are not in aggregation function or in the group by statement. In most other DBMS it is not allowed to select such columns.

Comment: @qwerty Sorry for the mistake and thanks for the hint. I have changed it.